# How do I connect from Eclipse Neon to SAP Web IDE Full-Stack?

Tags: eclipse, sapui5, sap-web-ide

Is there a way to connect to SAP Web IDE Full-Stack from Eclipse Neon and see the program?

I installed all SAP plug-ins in Eclipse, but I don't know how to connect to SAP Web IDE Full-Stack

Comment: I want to view and edit UI5 programs in the cloud from Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

SAP Web IDE and Eclipse are separate IDEs. SAP Web IDE based on Eclipse Orion but it has a lot of modification. You can use git services (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, etc) for sharing code between IDEs. SAP Web IDE own configuration files for projects. Maybe you cannot show project like Web IDE in Eclipse.

Comment: There seems to be no way to share it.
Thank you for the information